# Reading specific columns from CSV Python

Tags: python

I am trying to parse through a CSV file and extract few columns from the CSV.

```
ID | Code | Phase |FBB | AM | Development status | AN REMARKS | stem | year |   IN -NAME |IN Year |Company                                                                                                      
L2106538 |Rs124 | 4 | | | Unknown | | -pre- | 1982 | Domoedne | 1982 | XYZ
```

I would like to group and extract few columns for uploading them to different models.

For example I would like to group first 3 columns to a model, next two to a different model, first column and the 6, 7 to a different model and so on.

I also need to keep the header of the file and store the data as key value pair so that I would know which column should go for a particular field in a model.

This is what I have so far.

```
def group_header_value(file):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(file, 'r'))# to have the header and get the data as a key value pair.
    all_result= []
    for row in reader:
        print row
        all_result.append(row)
    return all_result


def group_by_models(all_results):
    MD = range(1,3) # to get the required cols. 
    for every_row in all_results:
        contents = [(every_row[i] for i in MD)]
        print contents

def handle(self, *args, **options):
        database = options.get('database')
        filename = options.get('filename')
        all_results =  group_header_value(filename)
        print 'grouped_bymodel', group_by_models(all_results)
```

This is what I get when I try to get the contents
    grouped_by model:  at 0x7f9f5382e0f0>
     at 0x7f9f5382e0a0>
     at 0x7f9f5382e0f0>

Is there a different approach to extract particular columns in DictReader? how else can I extract required columns using DictReader. Thanks

Comment: Could I know the reason for a down vote?

Answer (score 1):

`(every_row[i] for i in MD)` is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). The syntax for a generator expression is (mostly) the same as that for a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), except that a generator expression is enclosed by parentheses, `(...)`, while a list comprehension uses brackets, `[...]`.

`[(every_row[i] for i in MD)]` is a list containing one element, the generator expression.

To fix your code with minimal changes, remove the parentheses:

```
def group_by_models(all_results):
    MD = range(1,3) # to get the required cols. 
    for every_row in all_results:
        contents = [every_row[i] for i in MD]
        print(contents)
```

---

You could also make `group_by_models` more reusable by making `MD` a parameter:

```
def group_by_models(all_results, MD=range(3)):
    for every_row in all_results:
        contents = [every_row[i] for i in MD]
        print(contents)
```

Comment: Sorry @unutbu, but that does't work. I get keyerror :1

Comment: Hi , If there is a better way for  this than using DictReader I can change my code accordingly. I am a beginner in Python and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That would happen if `1` isn't a key in the dict, `every_row`.
Remember that if you use `DictReader`, then each row is a dict whose keys are the field names given in the header. If the first three field names are `'ID', 'Code', 'Phase'`, then you could call `group_by_models(all_results, MD=['ID', 'Code', 'Phase'])`. Alternatively, use `csv.reader` instead of `csv.DictReader`. Then the rows will be lists, and then you could use `group_by_models(all_results, MD=range(3))` to access the first three fields.